# Certificate of infeasibility in python's linprog

Tags: python, linear-programming

I have an infeasible linear program in linprog and I would like to get a certificate of infeasibility. Formally, my linear program is of the form
`Ax <= b, x >= 0` and I want a vector v>=0 satisfying `v^T*A >= 0, v^T*b < 0`. Here is the output of the **linprog** call for my linear program:

```
 con: array([1.50333333])
 fun: 0.0
 message: "Phase 1 of the simplex method failed to find a feasible solution. The pseudo-  objective function evaluates to 4.5e+00 which exceeds the required tolerance of 1e-09 for a solution to be considered 'close enough' to zero to be a basic solution. Consider increasing the tolerance to be greater than 4.5e+00. If this tolerance is unacceptably  large the problem may be infeasible."
 nit: 8
 slack: array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.50333333,
    1.50333333, -1.51335556, -1.51335556,  0.        ,  0.        ])
 status: 2
 success: False
 x: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: What exactly are you referring to as "Python's linprog"? Do you mean https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html?

Comment: And what exactly qualifies as "certificate of infeasability"? How is the message "failed to find a feasible solution" no such certificate?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, I this is what I am using. I want a vector v as described in my question (or similar). Linear programming theory asserts such a vector exists if the LP is infeasible and as the name suggests, it can be used to quickly verify that the LP is indeed infeasible.

Comment: Could you not solve another LP with  `v^T*A >= 0, v^T*b < 0`?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Of course, this is what I am currently doing. The documentation at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.linprog-interior-point.html claims "This particular implementation uses a homogeneous self-dual formulation, which provides certificates of infeasibility or unboundedness where applicable.", so I was hoping I wouldn't have to do it "manually".

Comment: It just does not return the duals.